# Is it possible to mix 2 ORMS in same web app?

Tags: python, flask, flask-sqlalchemy, flask-mysql

So is it possible to mix 2 ORM's in same web app,and if so how optimal would it be ? Why so?
- I'm working on a web app in flask using flask-mysqldb and I came to a point where I need to implement an auth system, and on flask-mysqldb there's no secure way to do it.
- With that said now I'm trying to implement flask-security but it only works on flask-sqlalchemy so I'm trying to mix sqlalchemy with mysqldb and before that I want to know if it's optimal and if it works.That would lead to using user auth along sqlalchemy and other data to mysqldb.Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible, but not recommended. Consider this:

- Half of your app will not benefit from anything a proper ORM offers
- Adding a field to the table means editing raw SQL in many places, and then changing the model.
  Don't forget to keep them in sync.

Alternatively, you can port everything that uses raw mysqldb to use SQLAlchemy:

- Need to add a field to your table? Just change the model in one place.
- Don't like SQL queries that ORM generates for you? You still have a low-level control over this.

Comment: Just to add to your answer - if you do need low level db queries there is SqlAlchemy Core -http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/ - which offers low level sql support.

Answer (score 3):

You can have a module for each orm. One module can be called auth_db and the other can be called data_db. In your main app file just import both modules and initialize the database connections. That being said, this approach will be harder to maintain in the future, and harder for other developers to understand what's going on. I'd recommend moving your flask-mysqldb code to sqlalchemy so that you are only using one ORM.